# Migrate customers and orders from 1.4 to 1.8

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, database-migration

I want to export all the tables that contain information about orders and customers from my old database to my new one.

So, I try to export this tables :

```
customer_address_entity
customer_address_entity_datetime
customer_address_entity_decimal
customer_address_entity_int
customer_address_entity_text
customer_address_entity_varchar
customer_eav_attribute
customer_eav_attribute_website
customer_entity
customer_entity_datetime
customer_entity_decimal
customer_entity_int
customer_entity_text
customer_entity_varchar
customer_form_attribute
customer_group

sales_flat_order
sales_flat_order_address
sales_flat_order_grid
sales_flat_order_item
sales_flat_order_payment
sales_flat_order_status_history
sales_order_status
sales_order_status_label
sales_order_status_state
sales_order_tax
sales_order_tax_item

directory_country
directory_country_format
directory_country_region
directory_country_region_name
directory_currency_rate

catalog_eav_attribute

eav_attribute
eav_attribute_group
eav_attribute_label
eav_attribute_option
eav_attribute_option_value
eav_attribute_set
eav_entity
eav_entity_attribute
eav_entity_datetime
eav_entity_decimal
eav_entity_int
eav_entity_store
eav_entity_text
eav_entity_type
eav_entity_varchar

log_customer
newsletter_subscriber
```

But It doesn't work, It migrate the orders and the customers but I cannot create a new account or make an order.

Do I need more or less table ?
Do you know another simple methode to import/export orders/customers ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting selected tables from Magento 1.4 old database. Try to connect your old database with new magento installation. It will update the database and you will get all your data in new website.

Please empty all log tables, report_compared_product_index table, report_viewed_product_index table before connecting the database with new magento installation.

Hope this help !!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a solution. I do that first to migrate from my 1.4 live website to my dev website. But now, my database is custom... And of course, during the time I develop the new website, new orders were made on the live website.

Is there a good extension maybe ?

Comment: then you can use cart 2 cart migration service. it is paid service.